# Specify CSS files per Module in angular2

Tags: angular

I have angular 2 project which have 2 Modules, one for web and one for admin.

I put the main styles for web in `style.css` (specified in .angular-cli.json)

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

and it work great, but the `style.css` code appear every where in both web and admin, i want to separate it completely.

is there any way to set specific CSS style files for each Module?

Answer (score 3):

for the 2 modules that you have, web module can have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-web',
  templateUrl: './web.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./web.component.css']
})
```

and admin module can have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
```

The file linked in `styleUrl` only applies to that component. so you can separate the css styles for each component this way.

If your styles are very short and you don't want to create a separate file for each component, there are other ways of applying styles to a particular component: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html